# Binding to Path ImageView in MvvmCross for MonoDroid/Android

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In my case path `"MyZooSnap.Core;component/Resources/Images/i.jpg"`.
How to convert path for Android `ImageView`?
In order to use it in the following binding:

```
{'AssetImagePath':{'Path':'ImagePath'}}
```

[More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914544/ssue-with-binding-to-gridlayout-to-android)

[similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876406/how-to-bind-an-image-src-to-resource-drawable-image-with-mvvmcross)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick answer:

- if your Android image file is stored in `assets/images/i1.png`
- then make sure it is marked as an `AndroidAsset`
- then your path needs to be `images/i1.png`

---

Longer answer:

Ideally your ViewModel should be platform independent and not know about View concerns.

So your ViewModel might perhaps expose a property like:

```
 private GameState _state;
 public GameState State 
 { 
     get { return _state; }
     set { _state = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => State); }
 }
```

where GameState is an enumeration like:

```
 public enum GameState
 {
     Stopped,
     Running,
     Paused,
     GameOver
 }
```

you might then have images representing these states in an assets structure like:

```
/assets/gamestates/stopped.png
/assets/gamestates/running.png
/assets/gamestates/paused.png
/assets/gamestates/gameover.png
```

where each of those files is marked with BuildAction of AndroidAsset.

To then display the correct image in the UI, you would need a value converter like:

```
public class GameStateConverter
    : MvxBaseValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Format("gamestates/{0}.png", ((GameState)value).ToString().ToLower());
    }
}
```

mapped in using a Converters wrapper like:

```
public class Converters
{
    public readonly GameStateConverter GameState = new GameStateConverter();
}
```

which is configured in setup.cs using:

```
    protected override IEnumerable<Type> ValueConverterHolders
    {
        get { return new[] { typeof(Converters) }; }
    }
```

With this in place, then your axml binding statement would be:

```
    {'AssetImagePath':{'Path':'State', 'Converter':'GameState'}}
```

---

For an alternative approach using resources instead of assets, see `MvxButtonIconBinding` in [Іssue with binding to GridLayout to Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914544/ssue-with-binding-to-gridlayout-to-android)

Comment: I wanted to clarify. Images should always be included in the project UI? Yes?

Comment: Yes - Android can now do some 'resource bundling' but in general all resources have to go in the UI project. If you want to share image files between Android, WP7, etc, then you can do 'Add As Link' within Visual Studio.

Comment: Post questions with significant detail, with code and with screenshots. No-one can help you if all you post is 'I could not fix the problem'

Comment: is it possible to use resource most suitable for current density instead of asset which has the only size?

Answer (score 0):

I could not fix the problem.
My MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainMenuViewModel
    : MvxViewModel
{
    private const string path = "myimage";

    public List<SquareModel> Items { get; set; }

    public IMvxCommand ShowItemCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxRelayCommand<Type>((type) => this.RequestNavigate(typeof(MainMenuViewModel)));
        }
    }

    public MainMenuViewModel()
    {
        Items = GetCollection();
    }

    public List<SquareModel> GetCollection()
    {
        List<SquareModel> col = new List<SquareModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            col.Add(new SquareModel { ID = i, PathImage = path });
        }
        return col;
    }
}
```

My Converts.cs

```
public class Converters
{
    public readonly PathImageConverter GameImage = new PathImageConverter();
}
```

My PathImageConverter.cs

```
public class PathImageConverter
    : MvxBaseValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Format("squareresources/{0}.png", value.ToString().ToLower());
    }
}
```

My Setup.cs

```
public class Setup
    : MvxBaseAndroidBindingSetup
{
    public Setup(Context applicationContext)
        : base(applicationContext)
    {
    }

    protected override MvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new App();
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Type> ValueConverterHolders
    {
        get { return new[] { typeof(Converters.Converters) }; }
    }
}
```

My GameView.axml

```
<cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.android.views.MvxBindableGridView
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/MyZooSnap.UI"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:numColumns="4"
                  android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                  android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/itemimage"
                  local:MvxBind="{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'Items'}}" />
```

My ItemImage.axml

```
<ImageView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/MyZooSnap.UI"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="10dp"
  local:MvxBind="{'AssetImagePath':{'Path':'PathImage', 'Converter':'GameImage'}}"
```

/>

My UI project
:[image]

Comment: I checked the path to the image binding correctly. Probably a problem with the same path.

Comment: At a guess, this is just a pathing issue - remember Android is Linux - so is CaseSensitive - so `Square` is not `square`. Best bet is to start with trying to bind a file in assets/i1.png then build up to more complex patterns...

Answer (score 0):

When the image is placed in the folder Assets and indicates simply indicate the name of the picture - it works.
And when it create another folder and specify the path:

```
/asset/folder/image.png
asset/folder/image.png
/folder/image.png
folder/image.png
```

Does not work!

Answer (score 0):

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    local:MvxBind="AssetImagePath PathImage,Converter=GameImage" />
```

Should work also